# Define a map type using json-schema v4

Tags: json, dictionary, cassandra, jsonschema

I'm trying to define a referenced schema for use as a Cassandra CQL map type with text fields.  Specifically, I want to map URIs to strings.

Right now I have:

```
"scope": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "uri": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uri"
        },
        "permission": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["read_only", "read_write", "write_only"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["uri", "permission"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
```

This is good for data like

```
{"uri":"http://example.com",
  "permission": "read_only"}
```

But I want a schema for data like

```
{"http://example.com": "read_only"}
```

http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html has a solution:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^S_": { "type": "string" },
    "^I_": { "type": "integer" }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that I'd have to define a built-in format with a regular expression.  Looking at examples of regexs for URIs makes me want to avoid this.

Since the number of URIs I have are limited, mapping enum to enum would also be a solution.  Is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can be permitted to answer my own question, I believe the solution is to use a PatternProperties definition for the key, with a very specific regex.  The value can be any type supported by json-schema, including another regex.  In my case, it's an enum.

So the definition looks something like-

```
  "patternProperties": {
    "^https:\/\/www.example.com\/auth\/\\w+$": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["read_only", "read_write", "write_only"]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
```